# Right-align the drop-down portion of the ComboBox in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, alignment

This question is NOT about aligning the text in the display or drop-down areas of the combobox.

There is a property named `DropDownWidth` that controls the width of the dropped-down portion. In my case, the combobox is located at the extreme right of a form. If the `DropDownWidth` exceeds the width of the combobox, the dropped-down area falls off the form (as well as the screen if the form is maximized).

Is there a way to align the dropped-down area with the right of the combo box instead of the left?

[image: Screen shot]

**UPDATE:** This question targets WinForms (.NET 4.0).

Comment: AFAIK, there is no straight forward way of doing this other than having a custom combobox probably where you will have to manually find the required size and do adjustment accordingly.

Comment: i guess its possible in wpf. but it wont be easy to achieve same thing in winForms because i think some of combobox properties have no setter.